# Multiple bootstrap popovers are created instead of dismissing old one

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, popover

I'm creating event calendar and I need bootstrap popovers on inlined jquery UI datepicker.

Currently I have this (by some reason popover isn't created in jsfiddle at all:

https://jsfiddle.net/vxnhmeop/4/

but the problem is that when I click on the day with event new popover instance is created. if I click second time the new popover is created on top and the old popover stays also. How do I dismiss the old popover?

I've already tried replacing this line of code

```
$("td[title='" + title + "']").popover(options).popover('toggle');
```

with

```
$("td[title='" + title + "']").popover(options).popover('show');
$("td[title='" + title + "']").popover(options).popover('hide');
```

to see if atleast it hides like that but it failed.

Comment: Note that the fiddle is broken: no popup is displayed; one reson is that the `event` is null. Even if it's bypassed, no popover is shown.

Comment: Yea I know I mentioned it in my question and I don't know why it doesn't work there as its what I use in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove displayed popovers before showing new one.

Add this :

```
$('.popover').each(function (){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

before

```
$("td[title='" + title + "']").popover(options).popover('show');
```

and it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks it works! But still shouldn't `popover('toggle')` hide the old popover automatically? I mean if i click the same date multiple times I get multiple popovers anyway.